# How can I select the next available value in a column taking into account another column in SQL?

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL table:

```
    bid btype    Name      world    vi
    ---|----|------------ |--------|---------
    1  | 1  | Business 1  |  0     | 44
    2  | 4  | Business 2  |  0     | 55
    5  | 5  | Business 3  |  0     | 23
    3  | 1  | Business 4  |  1     | 99
    4  | 2  | Business 5  |  0     | 12
    6  | 3  | Business 6  |  0     | 14
    7  | 2  | Business 7  |  1     | 55
    8  | 1  | Business 8  |  2     | 66
    9  | 2  | Business 9  |  2     | 77
    10 | 1  | Business 10 |  3     | 88
```

What I want is to gradually increase the value in the "world" column according to its "btype", for example every single row starts with a value 0 in the "world column
as it's the first time such value in the "btype" column is inserted, what I want is to check if there's already a "btype" inserted so that the "world" column no longer will assume a value of 0 but 1 and so on...
What I want to achieve is that there can't be two rows sharing the same "btype" with the same "world", the "btype" can be the same but not the "world", it has to be different and I want
it to gradually increase.

How would I approach to do such thing?

Comment: You wouldn't normally store derived data.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this then?

Comment: Maybe you should use a secondary auto-increment. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't usually do queries like this, so I can't say for certain, but something *like* this should maybe do the trick.

```
INSERT INTO theTable(btype, Name, world, vi)
SELECT [val1]
   , [val2]
   , IFNULL((SELECT MAX(world) FROM theTable WHERE btype = [val1]),-1)+1
   , [val3]
;
```

*You might even be able to just include the 3rd select expression in a conventional INSERT...VALUES value list; but like I said, I don't usually do queries like this. (I'm of the apparent minority that likes to check first before inserting; but not as a replacement for an appropriate uniqueness constraint.)*

Comment: A minority of 1 hopefully!

Comment: @Strawberry why hopefully?

Comment: Because, 'checking first' is unnecessary and liable to lead to a race condition, whereby the data set changes between the completion of step one and the commencement of step two.

Comment: @Strawberry Yeah, I figured something like that. I probably should have prefaced that most my tasks have involved either single server connecting to database or relatively few clients that for the most part operate on different tables; when concurrency issues are a concern, obviously "check first" isn't a reliable option, but I still tend to try to work the queries so a "catch the error" approach is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

E.g.:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(bid INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,btype INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
( 1,1),
( 2,4),
( 5,5),
( 3,1),
( 4,2),
( 6,3),
( 7,2),
( 8,1),
( 9,2),
(10,1);

SELECT bid
     , btype
     , i 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev=btype THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=0 END i
            , @prev:=btype prev 
         FROM my_table x
            ,( SELECT @i:=0,@prev:=null) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY btype,bid 
     ) n 
 ORDER 
    BY bid;
+-----+-------+------+
| bid | btype | i    |
+-----+-------+------+
|   1 |     1 |    0 |
|   2 |     4 |    0 |
|   3 |     1 |    1 |
|   4 |     2 |    0 |
|   5 |     5 |    0 |
|   6 |     3 |    0 |
|   7 |     2 |    1 |
|   8 |     1 |    2 |
|   9 |     2 |    2 |
|  10 |     1 |    3 |
+-----+-------+------+
```